# Case statement in JOIN slows the performance of the query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Case statement in JOIN slows the performance of the query, is there any way to improve to make the query performance faster

```
SELECT  A.TestColumn
FROM A with(nolock) 
INNER JOIN B with(nolock) 
  ON A.ID = B.ID  
  and A.InvoiceNo = CASE WHEN B.InvoiceType=2 
                    THEN B.MainInvoiceNo 
                    ELSE B.InvoiceNo END
```

Comment: A `CASE` is non-SARGable. Use proper boolean logic with `AND` and `OR` statements. Also, do you *need* those `NOLOCK` hints? Do you fully understand the consequences of using it? It isn't a magic "go faster button".

Comment: `and (A.InvoiceNo = B.MainInvoiceNo AND B.InvoiceType = 2 OR A.InvoiceNo = B.InvoiceNo AND B.InvoiceType <> 2)` may be faster, but it may not. It can depend on exact indexing and other factors

Comment: Not sure those brackets are correct in the above mind, @Charlieface .

Comment: @Larnu `AND` precedes `OR` in order of operations

Comment: and you and `AND` both before and *after* your `OR` @Charlieface. You *far* better off using brackets to be explicit.

Comment: In many cases you would be better off with two queries each using one condition and `union all` the results

Comment: Tried with Union and it is faster than CASE

Answer (score 3):

Try :

**1) with the valued CASE**

```
SELECT A.TestColumn
FROM   A
       INNER JOIN B
           ON A.ID = B.ID  and  
           A.InvoiceNo = CASE B.InvoiceType 
                            WHEN 2 THEN B.MainInvoiceNo 
                            ELSE B.InvoiceNo 
                         END
```

**2) with a UNION ALL**

```
SELECT A.TestColumn
FROM   A
       INNER JOIN B
           ON A.ID = B.ID  and  
           A.InvoiceNo = B.MainInvoiceNo 
WHERE  B.InvoiceType=2
UNION ALL
SELECT A.TestColumn
FROM   A
       INNER JOIN B
           ON A.ID = B.ID  and  
           A.InvoiceNo = B.InvoiceNo
WHERE  B.InvoiceType<>2
```

Answer (score 0):

probably using union will be the best performant :

```
SELECT  A.TestColumn
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B 
  ON A.ID = B.ID  
  and B.InvoiceType=2 
  and A.InvoiceNo = B.MainInvoiceNo 
union all 
SELECT  A.TestColumn
FROM A with(nolock) 
INNER JOIN B with(nolock) 
  ON A.ID = B.ID  
  and B.InvoiceType <> 2
  and A.InvoiceNo =  B.InvoiceNo
```

but also you can try using OR :

```
SELECT  A.TestColumn
FROM A with(nolock) 
INNER JOIN B with(nolock) 
  ON A.ID = B.ID  
  and 
   ( 
   (B.InvoiceType= 2  and A.InvoiceNo = B.MainInvoiceNo)
   or 
   (B.InvoiceType<> 2  and A.InvoiceNo = B.InvoiceNo)   
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `case expression` as part of the join criteria will be forcing SQL server to *scan* your index (probably a table scan if `id` is a clustered index).

Depending on the cardinality of your data and expected rows for each join condition, using two separate queries with the results `unioned` can yield better performance.

This is because for each individual query the optimiser can likely utilise an *index seek* resulting in far few `logical reads` overall.

Also since you are only returning data from `A` you could try using `exists`

```
Select A.TestColumn
from A
where exists (
  select * from B where B.Id = A.Id and B.InvoiceType=2 and A.InvoiceNo=B.MainInvoiceNo
)
or exists (
  select * from B where B.Id=A.Id and B.InvoiceNo = A.InvoiceNo 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two `LEFT JOIN`s and a `WHERE`

```
SELECT A.TestColumn
FROM A LEFT JOIN
     B B1
     ON A.ID = B1.ID AND
        B1.InvoiceType = 2
        A.InvoiceNo = B.MainInvoiceNo LEFT JOIN
     B B2
     ON A.ID = B2.ID AND
        A.InvoiceNo = B2.InvoiceNo 
WHERE B1.ID IS NOT NULL OR B2.ID IS NOT NULL;
```

SQL Server should find it much easier to implement an efficient execution plan.  I would recommend indexes on `B(ID, MainInvoiceNo, InvoiceType)` and `B(ID, InvoiceNo)`.